# How to safely destroy a ScrolledFrame in ttkbootstrap Python?

Tags: python, linux, tkinter, ttkbootstrap

I was creating a multipage application using ttkbootsrtap in python. Here is the code for one of those pages:

```
class EnterDataPage:
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root = root
        self.scrolled_frame = ScrolledFrame(self.root,height=400)
        self.scrolled_frame.pack(fill=X,expand=YES)

        enter_data_frame = ttk.Frame(self.scrolled_frame, bootstyle=DARK,padding=10)
        enter_data_frame.pack(pady=20,fill=X)

        name_label = ttk.Label(enter_data_frame,text="NAME",font=("Calibri", 14,"bold"),bootstyle="inverse-dark")
        name_label.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=10)
        name_entry = ttk.Entry(enter_data_frame)
        name_entry.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=10)

        date_label = ttk.Label(enter_data_frame,text="DATE",font=("Calibri", 14,"bold"),bootstyle="inverse-dark")
        date_label.grid(row=0,column=2,padx=10)
        date_entry = ttk.DateEntry(enter_data_frame)
        date_entry.grid(row=0,column=3,padx=10)

        add_remove_entry_frame = ttk.Frame(self.scrolled_frame,bootstyle=DARK,padding=10)
        add_remove_entry_frame.pack(pady=10)
        add_button = ttk.Button(add_remove_entry_frame,text="ADD")
        add_button.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=10,pady=10)
        remove_button = ttk.Button(add_remove_entry_frame,text="REMOVE")
        remove_button.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=10,pady=10)

        
        self.back_button = ttk.Button(self.root, text="BACK",command=self.backToHomePage)
        self.back_button.pack(pady=50)

    def clearPage(self):
        self.scrolled_frame.forget()
        self.scrolled_frame.destroy()
        self.back_button.destroy()

    def backToHomePage(self):
        self.clearPage()
        HomePage(self. Root)
```

The issue is that when the self.scrolled_frame.destroy() function gets called, it shows a bunch of errors and the application crashes.

Here is the error it shows:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/rohannag/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ttkbootstrap/scrolled.py", line 455, in _on_leave
    self.disable_scrolling()
  File "/home/rohannag/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ttkbootstrap/scrolled.py", line 414, in disable_scrolling
    self._del_scroll_binding(self)
  File "/home/rohannag/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ttkbootstrap/scrolled.py", line 394, in _del_scroll_binding       
    children = parent.winfo_children()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1106, in winfo_children
    self.tk.call('winfo', 'children', self._w)):
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
_tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".!frame.!scrolledframe"
```

Please help me out. I can't find the solution anywhere. I simply want to destroy the ScrolledFrame in order to load the next page.

Comment: This looks like a bug in the ttkbootstrap.scrolled module.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the object returned by `ScrolledFrame()` is the internal frame created inside another outer frame (referenced by an attribute `container`, see official [document](https://ttkbootstrap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/scrolled/scrolledframe/#ttkbootstrap.scrolled.ScrolledFrame)).  So calling its `destroy()` will only destroy the internal frame, not the outer frame.

You need to destroy the outer frame instead:

```py
def clearPage(self):
    # destroy the outer frame of `ScrolledFrame`
    # which is referenced by the attribute `container`
    self.scrolled_frame.container.destroy()
    self.back_button.destroy()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man! Appreciate your help